# What is .database file used for in SSIS solution

Tags: .net, ssis

What is the .database file used for in a SSIS package?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Quoting MSDN's page on [Integration Services Projects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms138028.aspx)

> Files in Integration Services Projects
>
> When you add a new or an existing
>   Integration Services project to a
>   solution, Business Intelligence
>   Development Studio creates project
>   files that have the extensions .dtproj
>   and .dtproj.user and .database.
>
> - The *.dtproj file contains information about project
>     configurations and items such as data
>     sources and packages.
> - The *.dtproj.user file contains information about your preferences for
>     working with the project.
> - The *.database file contains information that Business Intelligence
>     Development Studio requires to open
>     the Integration Services project.